# Nginx X-Accel-Redirect config for Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, x-sendfile, x-accel-redirect

In all the tutorials one may come across for setting up X-Accel-Redirect for nginx, there is always a bit about indicating a certain location is private, like so:

```
location /protected/ {
  internal;
  root   /some/path;
}
```

The files I'm sending to my users are in RAILS_ROOT/private_uploads. This is ***not*** inside the public folder, meaning that there are no URLs that point to directly to the files in this folder.

So am I correct in assuming I can ignore that bit of nginx config for my setup? If not, what config would I need?

I'm using Passenger, btw, and my config is really basic:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name mydomain.com;
  root RAILS_ROOT/public;
  passenger_enabled on;
}
```

Comment: When you say "I can ignore that bit of nginx config for my setup", what do you mean?

Comment: That it's not necessary for my Rails setup.

Comment: Well, if you want to accelerate the downloads of your private files in your `private_uploads` directory, it certainly is necessary.  The fact that no URLs point directly to it (nor should they) is beside the point.

Comment: Hmmm, well that's what I'm trying to figure out, but I'm not so sure. My app is still setting the  X-Accel-Redirect header when it does a send_file, and I've verified nginx is handling the download. It appears to me marking a location as "internal" is for security purposes, is it not? But since all incoming paths go through Rails and are authenticated there, it seems to me like I don't need to do that... does this make any sense?